# Where can I get SOAP req/resp xmls on Weblogic?

Tags: soap, logging, weblogic

I am trouble-shooting Web Service deployed on Weblogic 9. Where can I get SOAP req/resp xmls?
On Weblogic admin console or in the logging files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide WebLogic version, I am adding a link to how you do it in WebLogic 8.1. Might also work in newer versions as well.
[Debugging Errors While Invoking Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81b/webserv/client.html#1055831)

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I view SOAP Message on admin console?

Comment: I don't know, never heard of it. But I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the Weblogic Server command line parameters, that is, you are not allowed to add `-Dweblogic.webservice.verbose=true`, your webapp can force it in the following way:

```
weblogic.wsee.util.Verbose.setVerbose(true);
weblogic.wsee.util.Verbose.setupLogging();
```

(Works on Weblogic 10.3.5, logging of client-side JAX-RPC requests/responses, that is stubs generated by Weblogic's clientgen)

The xml dumps are printed in the standard output.